# Expanding view on click

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am working in angular, I think this question is asked here, but I did not get what I wanted, please suggest me ideas for doing this.

Basically, I have buttons like this with my HTML,

[image]

Now when user clicks on one of the button, it should display a list ,just like below image,

[image]

I have taken these examples from https://material.angular.io/components/categories

I have coded my buttons, but unable to get the logic after clicking the button, the view below button should expand and show the list. 
please help me

Comment: Any stackblitz sample that we can look at? Also it will show your effort to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements seems similar to

- https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

Also, you can use Primeng's Accordion if it suits your requirement

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion

An alternate way to achieve this you can do this using show/hide using `*ngIf`.